# The method write(int) in the type BufferedWriter is not applicable for the arguments (Long)

Tags: java, long-integer, bufferedwriter

I am getting the above error when I try this

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < uaCount.get(args[1]).occurrences ; i++)
    {
        out.write(uaCount.get(args[1]).singleValues.get(i));
    }
```

Occurrences and singleValues are defined here:

```
public static class NumberHolder
{
    public int occurrences = 0;
    public int sumtime_in_milliseconds = 0; 
    public ArrayList<Long> singleValues = new ArrayList<Long>();
}
```

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Well we know nothing about `uaCount`, which doesn't help. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You need to define what output you're expecting...

Comment: uaCount is my hashmap, I am just trying to print out the `singleValues` line by line, I would add an `out.newLine();` after the `out.write` statement

Comment: `BufferedWriter.write(int i)` writes `i` *interpreted as a character*.  It does not write the number `i`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(int)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the title of the question, my *guess* is that you just want to use `String.valueOf` to create a string:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < uaCount.get(args[1]).occurrences ; i++)
{
    out.write(String.valueOf(uaCount.get(args[1]).singleValues.get(i)));
}
```

Note that there'll be no separator between values that way though. I'd also suggest that for readability, you'd write something like:

```
NumberHolder holder = uaCount.get(args[1]);
for (int i = 0; i < holder.occurrences; i++)
{
    long value = holder.singleValues.get(i);
    out.write(String.valueOf(value));
    // Maybe out.write(" ") or something similar, as a separator?
}
```

Additionally, I'd *strongly* recommend against using public fields as you're currently doing. Try to encapsulate your types more carefully. And if `occurrences` is actually the size of the list, you can just use the enhanced `for` loop to simplify things. For example:

```
for (long value : uaCount.get(args[1]).getSingleValues()) {
    out.write(String.valueOf(value));
}
```

Comment: [`String.valueOf` docs for reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(long))

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
public ArrayList<Long> singleValues = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

to

```
public ArrayList<Integer> singleValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

would remove the error. Of course, you will then want to avoid placing any long or Long values in singleValues.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of java.io.BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html):

> Writes text to a character-output stream, buffering characters so as
>   to provide for the efficient writing of single characters, arrays, and
>   strings.

Long is not a text, [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has proposed the solution, convert Long to String with [String.valuesOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28long%29).

Answer (score -2):

change it to 
`(int)(long)out.write(uaCount.get(args[1]).singleValues.get(i));`.
you have to cast Long to integer

Comment: Why to type cast all that when you can use `Long#intValue`

Comment: And BufferedWriter handle int as character, it's not the intent of the OP.